# Specifying Figure Location With Figure Star

Tags: floats

I am using a two-column document and I need a figure to cover both columns, hence I am using the figure* environment. The problem is that I need the figure on the first page of the document. It appears that the normal [htb!], etc have no effect. No matter what I try the image ends up on page number two.

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx, float}

\begin{document}
\section*{Secton1}

\begin{figure*}[hbt!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure1.pdf}
\caption{\textsf{Figure Caption.}}
\label{fig:Figure1}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: \documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twocolumn]

Comment: This is a report (funding proposal) and a key graphic needs to be on the first page. I would use Word or something but it doesn't look anywhere near as nice!

Answer (score 5):

`\twocolumn` has an optional argument that you can use to place something at the start:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx, float}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}
\captionof{figure}{\textsf{Figure Caption.}}\label{fig:Figure1}\par\bigskip}]

\section*{Secton1}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a bit manual fiddling (one has to change the height of the second column) one can also get an image at the bottom of the first page:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx, float}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section*{Secton1}
\begin{figure}[b]
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
 \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-A}
 \captionof{figure}{A figure caption}
 \end{minipage}}
\end{figure} 

\lipsum[1-5]
\enlargethispage{-6.65cm} %to make the second column shorter
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx,kantlipsum}
\title{My Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today\\~\\~\\ \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=7cm]{example-image} \\
    \captionof{figure}{My Figure} 
    \label{Fig:Label 1} 
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\kant % provides just dummy text 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. There may be a problem elsewhere in my document then, because this doesn't work for me. I have a title and section heading on the first page but also need the figure on the same page (ideally at the bottom)....

Comment: If I try the above it simply adds a page break where I want the figure, then places the figure at the top of page 2 and continues the text

Comment: @JohnDoe Well, I added a hack now! Posting a complete question from the very beginning is always preferable.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I may have to give up and use Word in this case. It is a very long document and has many packages. I get an "! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }" using this hack unfortunately.